# How could I save a file based on user input?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that generate .bmp images which will allow users to preview hexidecimal colors. Users can enter a hex code into the terminal, and I will generate an image file that is completely that color. Here`s my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "cpputils/graphics/image.h"

int HexToInteger(std::string hex) {
  // Only works on strings length 2.
  if (hex.size() != 2) {
    return -1;
  }
  // Convert hex string, base 16 string, to integer.
  const int kBaseSixteen = 16;
  return strtoul(hex.c_str(), nullptr, kBaseSixteen);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Enter a hex code: ";
  std::string hex_color;
  std::cin >> hex_color; 

  // Convert input string to three integers
  std::string red = hex_color.substr(0, 2); 
  std::string green = hex_color.substr(2, 2);
  std::string blue = hex_color.substr(4, 2);
 
  // Create graphic::Color object 
  int RedasInt = HexToInteger(red); 
  int GreenasInt = HexToInteger(green);
  int BlueasInt = HexToInteger(blue); 
  graphics::Color color(RedasInt, GreenasInt, BlueasInt);

  // Draw and save image
  graphics::Image image(100, 100);
  bool DrawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height,
                     graphics::Color color);
  image.SaveImageBmp(hex_color);
  // Output
  std::cout << "Color swatch saved to " << hex_color << ".bmp"; 
  return 0;
}
```

I received this error

```
Your program should save a file based on user input.
[FAILED] HexImageTest.ExecutesAndExits
```

Comment: is `DrawRectangle` supposed to be a function call? You've declared a function instead

Comment: This looks like a message from your automatic grading system. It could fail your program for any number of reasons and no one here has any idea what they could be. No one knows what cpputils/graphics/image.h is and what it does either.

Comment: Did you consider reading the `hex_color` as a hex value directly? `std::uint32_t hex_color; if(std::cin >> std::hex >> hex_color) { /* successfully read a hex value */ ...`

Comment: Test your code on your PC. You'll likely have better tools and those tools will almost certainly give better diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
  bool DrawRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height, graphics::Color color);
```

you just declaring the function instead of calling it.

You should write:

```
  DrawRectangle(0, 0, image.width-1, image.height-1, color);
```

to call the function. Depending on your library cpputils/graphics/image.h the `image.width` and `image.height` might have different names. Look for them.

Again, depending on your library 'image` could be involved in a different way into this. Check how you suppose to use it while you already have it in the code.